# Would this be a proper use of threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading

After reading various MSDN articles, tutorials, and posts on here I came up with a design for a windows service that I wanted to make sure my threading strategy is proper and won't lead to memory, cpu, database issues.

Here is the basic flow.

**MAIN THREAD**

1. Collect list of service to be loaded.
2. Loads each service.

**SERVICE THREAD** *(started by timer event on step 3)*

1. Start Service
2. Setup Timer - Setup so there is no overlapping, only 1 processing call can be made.
3. Processing method

   - Makes database call to get information which is a list of `Commands`.
   - Gathers a collection of `Handlers`.
   - Does a `Parallel.ForEach()` over the list of `Commands`.
   - Immediately does a normal `foreach()` over the `Handlers`

**COMMAND THREADS**

1. Command does a normal `foreach()` over the `Handlers` passing in the `Command`.
2. Each `Handler` executes code that may CRUD the database or reach out to various other services.

   - Due to the `Parallel.ForEach()` I am spinning up 1 new thread per `Command`.
   - There could be 1000+
   - Since each `Command` has multiple `Handlers` these `Handlers` will run on the same thread as the `Command`.
   - This is to prevent database clashes since each `Handler` will be working with the same set of data.
   - This is to make each `Command` wait on its own `Handler` threads.

**WAIT POINTS**

1. Service waits for all `Commands` to finish executing before firing another round of round of commands.
2. `Commands` wait for all `Handlers` to to finish.
3. `Handlers` wait for one to finish before moving onto the next.

**PERFORMANCE**

- 3000x FOREACH Console.WriteLine() avg. 160ms
- 3000x FORALL Console.WriteLine() avg. 275ms
- 3000x FOREACH DatabaseCallAsync() avg. 1200ms
- 3000x FORALL DatabaseCallAsync() avg. 600ms

Interesting how the normal foreach was faster with just the WriteLine() but twice as slow with the database call. I still have concern about competing for resources with the other services.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Do you recognize any immediate issues with this design?
2. Do you have any suggestions that would make it more efficient with resources and speed?
3. I am noticing extremely high CPU usage on all cores when running just `Console.WriteLines()` in the actual execution point, should I be limiting the threads?

   - I noticed when I used a normal `foreach()` it still had pretty high cpu usage but had more resting points, I still need to put a counter in there to see how many calls are actually being made for each to see which is actually processing more but right now I am just concerned with the high usage.

Comment: PLINQ is used for data processing, not concurrently executing multiple commands. `Parallel.ForEach` will block until all commands are processed. You gain nothing over plain Tasks or Dataflow ActionBlocks, but you *do* waste ThreadPool threads for long-running tasks

Comment: Thank you, so would sticking with the async/await tasks would be better or are you speaking of another task. There are so many variations related to this realm its not always clear when to use what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You do not need to use dedicated threads: a thread is an expensive object so it is generally better to use the thread pool since it will reuse threads to process your *work items*. Using a dedicated thread is a good idea if you need thread-local storage, thread identity, thread priorities, custom scheduling (picking work item from a stack or a priority queue rather than a queue), a higher priority than work items (if you have thousands of work items in the queue, a thread is likely to get a time slice earlier) or conversely if you want to leave the queue free for something else, etc.
- Enqueuing a work item on the thread pool is still a moderately expensive operation (above hundreds of nanoseconds). Besides the algorithm used to dynamically adjust the number of threads in the pool works best when each work item is not too long (let's say less than one millisecond). If your work items are longer than this or if they suffer a poor scalability (database or IO contention), you may want to limit the max number of threads in the pool.
- Some timers will enqueue their callbacks over the ThreadPool and some others on the UI. You need to check whether your timer will conflate with any other work you could have enqueued, especially long-running work items on the ThreadPool, and if it is important that your callbacks run before pending work items.
- Async/await are mostly necessary when the identity of the thread matters, typically for agents. For example the UI typically can only be manipulated from the UI thread (this is a thread affinity mechanism that serves as a synchronization pattern) and you often need to dispatch a task to a background thread from the UI thread then continue it later over the UI again. While on one hand your services look like agents, on the other hand it may be a design mistake as I just explained and anyway it does not seem like you need to dispatch continuations back to the service.

  However tasks are a nice abstraction to use and Parallel.Foreach, Task.Run and others will use the thread pool by default.

**Edited the async/await section to take into account the comments below from Robert Harvey**
**Edited to mention timers's callbacks.**

Comment: Your statement about async/await doesn't make sense to me.  async/await is a mechanism for reordering work so that processing can continue while you wait for a result; it doesn't necessarily spin up new background threads, doesn't have much to do with thread identity, and is not specifically confined to a UI thread (although it will work there).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_WhatHappensUnderstandinganAsyncMethod

Comment: More specifically, *"An await expression in an async method doesn’t block the current thread while the awaited task is running. Instead, the expression signs up the rest of the method as a continuation and returns control to the caller of the async method.

The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the method is active."*

Comment: So, would using the Async/Await pattern be the correct approach for what I am doing? I'd prefer if multiple `Commands` could process at the same time, or at least let others process while others are working.

Comment: "Only necessary" was too much so I will edit my message. Yet consider that most of the time, when you wait for a single task, why not instead run the continuation on the same thread as the work itself? This is either because you do not want to run the continuation on the same thread as the work (because the thread identity matters), or because the API you are using does not let you do this. The very fact that you want to move the work from one synchronization context (thread most of the time) to another is very much related to the agents/thread identity, or composability.

Comment: @Tony Async/await is not a way to distribute work to other threads, it is a way to chain work across multiple threads (multiple synchronization contexts actually). Flagging a method as async or invoking it with "await" does not make it run on another thread.

Comment: @Tony The question is: when do you need to wait? According to your description services do not need to wait for commands and commands run their handlers on the current thread through a simple foreach loop. If those handlers are only available through an asynchronous API, then await is a proper answer. But if they provide a synchronous (blocking) API, then there is no need for async/await.

Comment: @VictorVictis, the services do need to wait for commands though as I do not want another round kicked off till the first round finishes. I have that setup with the timer. The commands wait on the handlers and the handlers inside a command wait on each other as they are taken off the queue. My thought is each thread would process an item each and the thread pool would manage the creation and break down of the threads as they are needed. Does this make a difference?

Comment: @Tony You got a wrong definition of "work items". Just look at the thread pool in general and ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem especially. Regarding your second question, I am not sure how you configured the timer to prevent that two callbacks could not overlap. Anyway do you need this rule to be strictly adhered to or loosely? For the latter you could just use a timer that relies on the threadpool, that way your callback will only be ran once no work item is left in the queue (but some of them could still be running). (to be continued)

Comment: @Tony If instead you want something strict, with a per-service synchronization, you can use a tick-level synchronization (since you seem to already have one) and then use an ending synchronization through Parallel.ForEach or Task.WhenAll (I would recommend the latter if the callback is invoked on the ThreadPool because I assume that ForEach will monopolize the current thread and leave it idle). However if you do not already have a a tick-level synchronization, then it would be better to merge those two synchronizations into one.

Answer (score 0):

Your design looks solid, although, the slowest point of the entire operation is going to be the reads from the database. Consider using an `Async` call, as this will free up the processor to perform other actions as it awaits the return call from the database.

Your `Parallel.ForEach` is definitely the best option, while it does use the thread pool (as noted), it also separates the queue from the thread pool, and has essentially one queue per processor thus there is no waiting in a lock block as they ask for the next task. Then when they finish their queue, they go to the next one and ask it for some (incurring a small hit to performance, but much less than if they all used the same queue.)

The only question you may want to think about is: what does the main thread do as the supporting threads are running? If it is doing nothing, then it is just eating up processor time that could be spent elsewhere. Even if you have it (the main thread) sleep until the other threads are done, it comes alive every so often only to sleep again, and if you use something like a ManualResetEvent, which waits until the other thread has completed to continue, then it is needlessly taking up memory. Have it do something, even if it turns into a servicer thread.

In short, `Parallel.ForEach` = Good!

Use `Async` and `Await` for database calls

Don't create unneeded threads.

Comment: -1: When a thread blocks on I/O (like the reading the network socket connected to the database) the processor is reassigned to a runable thread.  Nor does the main thread 'eat up processor time' while it is idle.  Non-runable threads consume only memory.

Comment: The data access is asyncable, I haven't actually created the guts yet but I planned on using it so I can provide maximum processing on each thread, this is correct right? Should my CPU be maxing out? I am just doing Console.WriteLine() 3000x, I am concerned this will block other services on the server. Would it make sense to limit them to like 10?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that behind the scenes, what an async method would do is create a separate thread / worker that will lock up until it's finished reading its stream, and then signal your original thread. If your task needs the result to complete, there's not much point in designing it as async.